# Resize set of List Elements to width of widest list element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get my list elements in my pure css dropdown to be uniform size based on the width of the largest element in the ul. This is the current html:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="drop-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li onmouseover="SizeChildren('DropDown1')"><a href="#">Filler</a>
      <ul id="DropDown1">
        <li><a href="#">Filler1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Filler223456</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Filler212314235234523</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
<nav>
```

I run the SizeChildren function passing the parent containers id to the function (note: I realize there is redundant code in here, it's stuff I was messing with):

```
function SizeChildren(ElementID)
{
var WidthArray = new Array();

UOList = document.getElementById(ElementID);
WidthArray = UOList.getElementsByTagName('li');

var MaxWidth;

for(i = 0; i < WidthArray.length; i++)
{
  if(i == 0)
  {
    MaxWidth = WidthArray[i].offsetWidth;
  }
  else
  {
    var curr = WidthArray[i].offsetWidth;
    if(curr > MaxWidth)
    {
      MaxWidth = curr;
    }
  }
}

var nodes = document.getElementById(ElementID).childNodes;

for(i = 0; i < nodes.length;i++)
{
  if(nodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'li')
  {
    nodes[i].style.width = MaxWidth;
  }

}
}
```

There are two problems I am running into with the current code, first off, it is calculating the max width to be 82 (should be closer to 150 or close to it) and it is not actually setting the widths, meaning that nothing is actually changing on the page, and that I have no clue about, even with the max width getting miscalculated this portion of the code should still work, so what am I missing? I tried using .offsetWidth as well and that still produced no fruit.

I can't use JQuery, flex boxes, or anything like that, it has to be done in JavaScript if possible.